# TradingView Pinescript - how to TP/SL for all trades instead of auto-exit with new trades

Tags: pine-script, trading

I want to develop a strategy where every single trade that I enter will hit either the point of Take Profit or Stop Loss.
For example, I have a short entry with the exit settings as below:

`strategy.exit("TP/SL", "Short Entry", stop=low + ATR, limit=close - ATR)`

but if the next day there's a long entry, it will enter that long position and automatically close my previous short entry, making the exit settings useless.
Is there any ways to prevent this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search finally found it!
Just use `strategy.opentrades== 0` when your long or short condition is true:

```
long = (OSrsi and BullEng) and strategy.opentrades==0 
short = (OBrsi and BearEng) and strategy.opentrades==0
```

Use this condition to enter trades.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for answering but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the issue? Check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how to format code.

Comment: This is awesome! I tested and it worked! I think your additional code "and strategy.opentrades==0" makes the trade looks for any previously open trades before entering a new trade, thus making it always hit the TP/SL? This solution actually is not the best in my case (I want pyramidding - enter a few trades for the same pair), but for testing purpose this solved it. Thanks again!